# Updated Mac to MacOS Monterey and now vagrant up isn't working

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I updated my mac to Monterey. Then I tried to vagrant up in a project after I updated the virtual box and allowed permission in my System Preferences > Security & Privacy.

I get this error:

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "2f108a05-a574-4e42-b03d-36b2abfa8d26", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage: error: The virtual machine 'projectwebsite.test' has terminated unexpectedly during startup because of signal 10
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component MachineWrap, interface IMachine
```

What should I do to fix it? I looked at solutions and it said something about GUI and Headless. I came across this article saying that VBoxHeadline doesn't run in macOS Monterey. (https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20636). So I have to configure vagrant to run in gui

So the options I have:

1. roll back to previous MacOS version
2. Configure vagrant
3. What else?

Question: How do I configure vagrant? This article is confusing: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/providers/virtualbox/configuration#gui-vs-headless. Where do I go to add this code?

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  v.gui = true
end
```

So confused about all those things.

Comment: try beta release 6.1.29 works as expected without enforcing gui :) https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VirtualBox-6.1.29-148164-OSX.dmg

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a fix — https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12557#issuecomment-958183899

Two more clues:

- I may add that if your local website still does not open as if not loading at all, then you should modify macos /etc/hosts and change ip address to 192.168.56.* (* — put any number, but it should be under 192.168.56., as per new network configuration changes).
- If the php still not working, you might need to restart an fpm:

  sudo service php7.4-fpm restart

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the virtualbox with homebrew in a terminal

brew install virtualbox

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The new build of VirtualBox from this tickets works for me.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20636

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/20637

> Where do I go to add this code?

You need to put it into your Vagrantfile

Example:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    v.gui = true
  end
end
```